# SAS---how to create histograms plot with specific bin in certain range

Tags: sas, histogram

I attempt to crate histograms plot via `proc univariate`. The target is to crate the distribution with bins of 0.1 width from 0 to 1.5 and then all the remaining in one bin.

I applied the following code to identify the range from 0 to 1.5, while it cannot manage the rest. How can I correct the code?

```
proc univariate data=HAVE;
where pred between 0 and 1.5;
var pred;
histogram pred/ vscale=percent midpoints=0 to 2 by 0.1 normal (noprint);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following code to combine two Histograms by creating two variables from one variable:

```
/*Temporary DS with values ranging from 01. to 2.0*/
data have;
do i=0.1 to 2.0 by 0.1;
    output;
end;
rename i=pred;
run;

/*Creating two variables x(0.1-1.5) and y(1.6-2.0)*/
data have;
 set have;
 if pred<1.6 then x=pred;
 else y=pred;
 drop pred;
run;

/*Combine two Histograms*/
proc sgplot data=have;
   histogram x / nbins=15 binwidth=0.1;
   density x / type=normal;
   histogram y / nbins=5 binwidth=1.0;
   density y / type=normal;
   keylegend / location=inside position=topright noborder across=2;
   xaxis display=(nolabel) values=(0.1 to 2.5 by 0.1);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own groups
2. Create a format so it shows the way you'd like
3. Plot it with SGPLOT

   ```
   *create your own groups for data, especially the last group;
   data mileage;
   set sashelp.cars;
   mpg_group=floor(mpg_highway / 10);

   if mpg_group in (5, 6, 7) then
       mpg_group=5;
   keep mpg_highway mpg_group;
   run;

   *format to control display;

   proc format;
   value mpg_fmt 1='0 to 10' 2='11 to 20' 3='21 to 30' 4='31 to 40' 5='40+';
   run;

   *plot the data;
   proc sgplot data=mileage;
   vbar mpg_group /stat=freq barwidth=1;
   format mpg_group mpg_fmt.;
   run;
   ```